# force:apex:test:run throws error in CI: "No tests were able to be executed on the org. Please verify that the source code has been pushed correctly"

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, failing-tests, ci

Upon attempting to run Apex tests via CI using command "force:apex:test:run" in a packaging org, I get the following error:
"An unknown exception occurred. No tests were able to be executed on the org. Please verify that the source code has been pushed correctly". Not getting any details about any failing tests.

Everything was working fine until recently, no breaking changes were done to CI script or code.
I have also tried compiling all classes and running all tests on the CI packaging org manually, everything compiles and passes successfully.

Does anyone have any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Is this happening on prod? Does all Apex on the org compile, not just looking at the test classes? Have you compiled and run all tests manually on the org?

Comment: Thank you for the questions, I have added this info to description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 12 hours later and the error is gone.
No changes were done to code/org settings from my side.
Those are the mysterious ways of Salesforce, I guess :)